# How to share images between multiple docker hosts?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

I have two hosts and docker is installed in each.

As we know, each docker stores the images in local `/var/lib/docker` directory.

So If I want to use some image, such as `ubuntu`, I must execute the `docker pull` to download from internet in each host.

I think it's slow.

Can I store the images in a shared disk array? Then have some host pull the image once, allowing every host, with access to the shared disk, to use the image directly.

Is it possible or good practice? Why docker is not designed like this?

It may need to hack the docker's source code to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this article

Dockerizing an Apt-Cacher-ng Service

http://docs.docker.com/examples/apt-cacher-ng/

extract

This container makes the second download of any package almost instant.

At least one node will be very fast, and I think it should possible to tell the second node to use the cache of the first node.

Edit : you can run your own registry, with a command similar to

`sudo docker run -p 5000:5000 registry`

see

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry

Comment: I think this is a apt cache, it cached the `apk` files. How if I have many different images, such as ubuntu, debian, redhat, centos, wordpress node.js and so on? So many images, I need to pull the image for the first time on every host.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think it still a waste of disk space. For example, I have 100 hosts, and one docker-registry, then each host and the docker-registry must have one copy in each. There are 101 images. If the image is on shared disk array, only one copy is enough.

Answer (score 0):

**Update in 2016.1.25 docker mirror feature is deprecated**

Therefore this answer is not applicable now, leave for reference

**Old info**

What you need is the mirror mode for docker registry, see https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/articles/registry_mirror/

It is supported directly from `docker-registry`

Surely you can use public mirror service locally.

Comment: I see the `docker registry`, I think there are still two problems:  1) It can avoid downloading images from internet, but still need to download from local network.    2) Every host that runs docker daemon, need to store one copy of the images.   If shared disk array can be used, one download and use anywhere, and one image copy on the shared disk is enough.

Comment: could be used as u stated, then you loose most of the power of docker. When u work for docker more, you will prefer to use docker registry.

Comment: also docker is client/server mode, it is possible to run one server  with shared folder.

Comment: @LarryCai your link directs now to a `404`. I suggest to edit it with: https://docs.docker.com/registry/.
It must be noticed that mirror registry are [not supported anymore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/registry_mirror/).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not supposed to work as explained by [cpuguy83](https://github.com/cpuguy83) at this [github/docker issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15887).

Indeed:

> The underlying storage driver would need to synchronize access.

Sharing `/var/lib/docker` is far [not enough and won't work](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15887#issuecomment-135480041)!

According to the [doc.docker.com/registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/):

> You should use the Registry if you want to:
>
> - tightly control where your images are being stored
> - fully own your images distribution pipeline
> - integrate image storage and distribution tightly into your in-house development workflow

So I guess that this is the (/your) best option to work this out (but [I guess that you got that info](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9935#issue-53587647) -- I just add it here to update the details).

Good luck!